# Using Wireshark to decrypt tls encrypted file with private key

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I have a packet encrypted with TLS in a .pcap file. I also have the private key in a .priv file.

How can I decrypt the .pcap file using Wireshark? I tried going to edit -> preferences -> protocols -> ssl -> edit -> new, but I am not sure what to enter in for the IP address, port?

How can I display the corresponding packet in Wireshark to find out the port and IP address? Is this the right way to decrypt the .pcap file in Wireshark using the private key?

Comment: I've always done this with a command line tool named ssldump: http://ssldump.sourceforge.net/

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456934/how-to-view-encrypted-application-data-in-wireshark): "How to view Encrypted Application Data in Wireshark"

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this myself but after a google search I have found this tutorial. You don't need to do every step, jump right to the "decrypt https part": [Write-up Codegate 2010 #7 - Decrypting HTTPS SSL/TLSv1 using RSA 768bits with Wireshark](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/03/codegate-decrypting-https-ssl-rsa-768.html)

I will add the relevant information nevertheless:

> **Decrypt https**
>
> Open Wireshark preferences file:
>
> - on Linux: `~/.wireshark/preferences`
> - on Windows: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Wireshark\preferences`
>
> Inform Wireshark that you want it to desegment SSL records and
> application data, and give it the private certificate for the https
> server we observed (192.168.100.4):
>
> ```
> ssl.desegment_ssl_records: TRUE 
> ssl.desegment_ssl_application_data: TRUE
> ssl.keys_list: 192.168.100.4,443,http,/home/stalkr/codegate/7/private.pem
> ```
>
> Fix the path to private certificate accordingly, on Windows use
> regular slashes /.
>
> Again, launch Wireshark and open the capture file. We can now see the
> application data: an HTTP GET request to index.html, and the response
> containing the flag.
> [image: Blockquote]

Have a look and let us know.

**Notes:**

- All this information belongs to "[StalkR's Blog](http://blog.stalkr.net/)" and I have added it here for convenience. Consider visiting the full blog entry since he may add some extra steps.
- Wireshark has changed naming from SSL to TLS

Comment: Thanks greatly for the help! I understand it better, however when I tried putting the details, it doesn't covert to HTTP, it instead says Encryption Alert. I think I might be putting the wrong IP address and port no. Which src address do we use, for instance in the above picture how do we know to use 192.168.100.4 instead of 192.168.100.2 and is the port no. always 443? This video also helped me : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQtur8fqErI and this link : http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL . Pls clarify.

Comment: any sources on how to do this in unix?

Comment: This can be found in the UI under Edit > Preferences > Protocol > SSL

Comment: And it's called TLS now